# Put a condition check and variable assignment in one 'if' statement

Tags: c

I am looking at some legacy C code and got confused. It is something like:

```
UINT A, B = 1;
if((A = B) == 1) {
   return(TRUE);
} else {
   return(FALSE);
}
```

We all know there will be a compiler warning if we do if(A = B), but here it looks like the 'if' is checking A against 1. Am I correct?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, it assigns the value of `B` to `A` (`A = B`), then it checks if the result of this assignment, which is `A` and evaluates to `1`, is equal to `1`.

So technically you are correct: On the way it checks `A` against `1`.

To make things easier to read, the code is equivalent to:

```
UINT A, B = 1;
A = B;
if(A == 1){
   return(TRUE);
} else {
   return(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Just because you can write the code the way it has been written in the question, doesn't mean you should. You should always prefer the code as written in this answer because it has no ambiguity.

Comment: How is the original ambiguous?  It was clear to you, tis clear to me.

Comment: It's useful to write it the way in the question in the cases where your result statements might then have to make that assignment. On the surface it saves you the memory/database access (realizing that the compiler might be smart enough to do that under the hood).

Answer (score 12):

Rather, your code is always assigning `B` to `A`, and it is moreover checking whether the value of `B` (and thus also `A`) is equal to `1`.

There's nothing "legacy" about this, this is generally a pretty handy idiom if you need the result of an operation but also want to check for errors:

```
int result;
if ((result = foo()) != -1)
{
  printf("The result is: %i\n", result);
}
else
{
   // panic
}
```

Comment: yeah your foo() check is just like those fopen() check. The code I see here is a bit more convoluted, which made me a bit confused...

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it on 1 line:

```
if ((A = B), A == 1)
```

does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. The value `A` has after the assignment will be compared to `1`.

This code sample is equivalent to just:

```
return (TRUE);
```

Comment: Exactly.I'm wondering if there would be a situation in which the assignment would fail.It makes sense if the check was for the return value of a function as Kerrek SB mentioned.

Comment: I expect the question is contrived to show this.. B would typically be unknown.

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to avoid if statements to make code more readable.

```
UINT A, B = 1;
bool fResult = false;

fResult = (A == B);

return(fResult);
```

And if there must be an condition to act on (not) equality, see this example.

```
UINT A, B = 1;
bool fResult = false;

fResult = (A == B);

if(fResult)
{
  doThis();
}
else
{
  doThat();
}

return(fResult);
```

Comment: It is even more valid, if it is noted fResult can be named to describe what kind of result it is. E.g., "readOnly" if it tested some numeric return code from a system call (just as an example - there could be named numeric constants in that particular example).