# Variable assignment inside a C++ 'if' statement

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, c++17, variable-assignment

In C++, the following is valid and I can run it without a problem:

```
int main(){
    if (int i=5)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, even though the following should also be valid, it gives me an error:

```
if ((int i=5) == 5)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

**Error:**

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     if ((int i=5) == 5)
          ^
test.cpp:4:10: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
test.cpp:5:36: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
         std::cout << i << std::endl;
                                        ^
```

Furthermore, in [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) the below code [must be valid](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c17-new-feature-else-switch-statements-initializers/) too, but it gives me a similar error again:

```
if (int i=5; i == 5)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

**Error:**

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:4:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
     if (int i=5; i == 5)
                ^
test.cpp:4:18: error: ‘i’ was not declared in this scope
     if (int i=5; i == 5)
                  ^
```

I am trying to compile with `g++ test.cpp -std=c++17`. `g++ --version` gives me `g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609`. What am I missing here?

Comment: @FoggyDay Yes you can declare a variable in an if condition. Try it. `if(int i=5)` works.

Comment: No matter if it is accepted by the compiler or not, what is the intent? What is the `if` statement supposed to test? Is the intent to ***limit the scope of variable `i`***? Is that case, a naked "`{}`" block can be used. It doesn't require an `if` statement. Or is the intent something else? Can you [make](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60700205/edit) the intent clear in the question? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: Here is a question with a similar structure, but without the (close by) declaration: *[Put a condition check and variable assignment in one 'if' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6860327/)*

Comment: Was the intent to limit the scope of variable `i`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`if ((int i=5) == 5)` is a syntax error. It does not match any supported syntax for `if` statements.  The syntax is *init-statement(optional) condition*, where *condition* could either be an expression, or a declaration with initializer. You can read more detail about the syntax [on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

`if (int i=5; i == 5)` is correct. However, you are using an old version of [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) that dates from before [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) was standardized. You would need to upgrade your compiler version.  According to [C++ Standards Support in GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx1z) this feature was added in GCC 7.

Comment: Yes I was wrong to do `if ((int i=5) == 5)`. Upgrading g++ to version 9 solved the second problem.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, I believe your compiler is right to reject

```
if ((int i=5) == 5)
```

because this is not legal C++ code. A variable declaration statement isn’t an expression, so you can’t treat `(int i = 5)` as an expression.

For the second one, I suspect you just need to update your compiler. g++ 5.6 is a fairly old version at this point, and I believe more updates versions of g++ will handle that code with no problem.